# Sort a filed with type string but contains string and number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A table has a filed with type varchar(50)

this filed contains number,string and mix like `1001`,`10012`,`1001b`

I want to write q query that sort it character by character :

```
1001

1001b

10012
```

Comment: Is the pattern always number + letter?

Comment: no,number or number+letter

Comment: Is it always one letter at the end?

Comment: Please, give a sample of your table. What did you try?

Comment: no,number or number+letter

Comment: @SajjadZare, if it's number + letter, is it only one letter?

Comment: no , combination of number and character : 1000abd,abd100,1000,100012,...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern splitter to split your string into number and characters. Here is **PatternSplitCM** taken from Dwain Camp's [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/):

```
-- PatternSplitCM will split a string based on a pattern of the form 
-- supported by LIKE and PATINDEX 
-- 
-- Created by: Chris Morris 12-Oct-2012 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PatternSplitCM]
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 

RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
        SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
        (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n)
    )

    SELECT
        ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
        [Matched]
    FROM (
        SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
        FROM numbers
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) y
    ) d
    GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper
```

Your final query would be:

```
;WITH tbl(string) AS(
    SELECT '10001' UNION ALL
    SELECT '100012' UNION ALL
    SELECT '10001b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b1000'
)
SELECT
    t.string,
    NumPart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Matched = 0 THEN CAST(s.Item AS INT) END),
    CharPart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Matched = 1 THEN s.Item END)
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternSplitCM(string, '%[^0-9]%') s
GROUP BY t.string
ORDER BY
    NumPart, CharPart
```